# How to return reference to value inside option while conditionaly modifying outer option

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have token inside Option. Before each operation, I need to check if token is valid or not. it might be expired. if it is expired, I want to set outer option to None and return Error so next time I will just get "No Token" Error.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Token {
    exp : u64
    //other cool stuff
}

fn is_valid<'a>(v : &'a mut Option<Token> ) -> Result<&'a mut Token, String> {
    match v {
        None => Err("No Token".into()),
        Some(v_) => {
            if v_.exp > 10 {
                *v = None;
                Err("Token Expired".into())
            }
            else {
                Ok(v_)
                // Err("erlgnerlg".into()) //commenting this out and comenting upper line also work.
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Some(Token { exp : 69 });

    //expecting "Token Expired" error
    println!("{:?} ", is_valid(&mut v)); 

    //expecting "No Token" error
    println!("{:?} ", is_valid(&mut v)); 
}
```

but it fails to compile.

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*v` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:13:17
   |
8  | fn is_valid<'a>(v : &'a mut Option<Token> ) -> Result<&'a mut Token, String> {
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
11 |         Some(v_) => {
   |              -- borrow of `*v` occurs here
12 |             if v_.exp > 10 {
13 |                 *v = None;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `*v` occurs here
...
17 |                 Ok(v_)
   |                 ------ returning this value requires that `v.0` is borrowed for `'a
```

if I dont assing None to outer option, my code compile. also in else block, if I return Err instead of Ok, it compiles fine. why does this happen and how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we can get another compiler error if we replace `*v = None` with `let _ = v.take()` (which does exactly the same thing). This yields the classic "second mutable borrow occurs here":

```
10 |         Some(v_) => {
   |              -- first mutable borrow occurs here
11 |             if v_.exp > 10 {
12 |                 let _ = v.take();
   |                         ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |                 Ok(v_)
   |                 ------ returning this value requires that `v.0` is borrowed for `'a`
```

And it makes sense: First, we destructured the borrowed `Option` to take a look inside, but then we want to change it while still having the reference to the inside of the `Option` lying around.

We can however capture all of your conditional logic with one `match` statement, using [match guards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html):

```rust
    match v {
        None => Err("No Token".into()),
        Some(v_) if v_.exp > 10 => {
            dbg!(v_.exp); // use v_ in _some_ way
            let _ = v.take(); // same as *v = None
            Err("Token Expired".into())
        }
        Some(v_) => Ok(v_)
    }
```

I am not *entirely* sure, why the compiler gets stuck on your version, but here is what I think happened: Your match arm returns a reference to the inner `Token` value *in some way*, thus the compiler deduces that this reference must be kept alive for the entire scope of the arm.

With the match guards, it can deduce that we never touch the contained value again and shorten the lifetime of the inner borrow (the one we implicitly did when matching against `Some(v_) if ...`). Note that the lifetime of this borrow ends precisely when we drop the previously contained value, as we can still use it in the line `dbg!(v_.exp)`.

Once this inner borrow is over, the outer borrow `v` is the only reference left and it is fine to touch the outer value in the match arm.

Answer (score 0):

The match mutably borrows `v` (for `v_`), so you're not allowed to use it anymore. You need to use `v_` instead - at least until it's dropped.

I also changed the names to `v_opt` and `v` for readability:

```rust
    match v_opt {
        None => Err("No Token".into()),
        Some(v) if v.exp > 10 => {
            drop(v);
            *v_opt = None;
            Err("Token Expired".into())
        }
        Some(v_) => Ok(v_)
    }
```